# 12V linear actuator with limit switches and reverse/forward Joystick

Tags: actuator, joystick

I am a 67years old fisherman from Greece. On my boot (Diesel mercedes motor) I want construct a linear actuator (from auto window wisher) to control the throtle (diesel pump).there is too many diagramms for that but I want that the actuator

1. in his first return (to the4 left) position stops once at idle position (first limit)
   from this position it must be possibile
   1a) increase or decrease rpm's
   1B) or
2. when triggered with a push button must goes back to motor off position (same direction to return)
3. To motor start, when I give 12V power,the actuator must go to idle position.

The reverse/forward will be released with a joystick type XD2-PA12 and with 2 N/O and 2 N/C control box contacts.
See Foto.
Anybody knows how to contact? will be very helpfully.
Sorry for my english (speak much better german)

[image: PLAN][image: JOYSTICK][image: BLOCK CONTACTS FOR JOYSTICK]